# taking the address of the result of std::vector<bool>::at(size_t), how to fix for C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

This function:

```
template<typename T>
void f(int stack, std::vector<T> *vec, void (*readItemFunc)(int, T*))
{
    // omitted irrelevant code

    for(size_t i = 0; i < sz; i++)
    {
        readItemFunc(stack, &vec->at(i));
    }
}
```

fails to compile, because of how `std::vector<bool>` is specialized. Clang++ reports this compile error:

> no viable conversion from `__bit_iterator<std::__1::vector<bool, std::__1::allocator<bool> >, false>` to `bool *`

In C++17 I could do:

```
template<typename T>
void f(int stack, std::vector<T> *vec, void (*readItemFunc)(int, T*))
{
    // omitted irrelevant code

    for(size_t i = 0; i < sz; i++)
    {
        if constexpr(std::is_same<T, bool>::value)
        {
            T v;
            readItemFunc(stack, &v);
            (*vec)[i] = v;
        }
        else
        {
            readItemFunc(stack, &vec->at(i));
        }
    }
}
```

however it would be the only line requiring C++17, while the rest of the project supports back to C++11, so I'd try to stick with C++11 until it makes sense.

Considering that the "omitted irrelevant code" is quite long, and depends on `T`, specializing `f()` for `bool` would involve a lot of code duplication.

In what other way I can solve this issue for C++11?

Comment: Does all the omitted irrelevant code depend on `T`? Can you factor it out into a single, templated (non-specialized) method and only specialize the part below? Alternatively (but similarly) you could just wrap the call to readItemFunc in a function like `<T> callReadItemFunc(int, vector<T>*, void (*)(int, T*))` that itself is specialized.

Comment: yes, making a wrapper to call `readItemFunc` and specialize it for bool seems to be the most concise way to it. I'm curious if someone comes up with a different solution...

Comment: Why pass `vec` as a pointer and not a reference? Why not have `readItemFunc` return a `T` instead of using an output parameter? Then you could just write `vec[i] = readItemFunc(stack);` for both cases.

Answer (score 4):

You can basically wrap your `T v; expression_that_modifies(&v); vec->at(i) = v;` in a class, where the `std::vector<bool>::reference` is assigned in the destructor that is called when the evaluation of the expression finishes.

For example,

```cpp
template<typename T>
T& wrap_vector_bool_reference(T& p) noexcept {
    return p;
}

struct vector_bool_wrapper {
    std::vector<bool>::reference ref;
    bool real_bool;
    vector_bool_wrapper(std::vector<bool>::reference r) noexcept : ref(r), real_bool(r) {}

    operator bool&() noexcept {
        return real_bool;
    }
    bool* operator&() noexcept {
        return &real_bool;
    }
    ~vector_bool_wrapper() {
        ref = real_bool;
    }
};

inline vector_bool_wrapper wrap_vector_bool_reference(std::vector<bool>::reference ref) noexcept {
    return vector_bool_wrapper(ref);
}


template<typename T>
void f(int stack, std::vector<T> *vec, void (*readItemFunc)(int, T*))
{
    // omitted irrelevant code

    for(size_t i = 0; i < sz; i++)
    {
        // No wrapper is applied if `T` isn't `bool`
        readItemFunc(stack, &wrap_vector_bool_reference(vec->at(i)));
    }
}
```

If you had multiple statements, you could just use an extra variable:

```cpp
{
    auto&& i = wrap_vector_bool_reference(vec->at(i));
    // i is `T&` normally, but `vector_bool_wrapper&&` if `T` is `bool`.

    // Can cast `i` to `T&`, like
    T& ref = i;
    T* ptr = &i;
}
```